# E/R diagrammer for Informix?

Tags: informix

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Server studio doesn't have relationship connectors.

Is there a good informix E/R diagrammer out there that generates the code automaticaly?

free would be nice...

UPDATE: Im wrong, it does have relationship connectors, it's just that you must define the foregin key and then execute, I didn't execute I thought saving the diagram would do... still sucks tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.

- [Erwin](http://www.ca.com/us/data-modeling.aspx) supports Informix.
- [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/studio) also supports Informix.
- I'm a little surprised that [SSJE](http://www.serverstudio.com/) does not have any ER diagramming facility - are you sure about that?  It has a Table Manager that is similar to what you want - but may not be part of the base offering distributed with IDS (IBM Informix Dynamic Server).
- Also look at the [Open Admin Tool](http://www.openadmintool.org/) (OAT).

Comment: can't seem to find a way in Server studio to connect tables with a relationship, I'm a total informix noob